# DataRows not updating with new data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a form that allows users to select a row from a DataGridView then make changes to them and have them update the row with the new data.

Here is the code that will execute when the save button is pressed

```
        matchBookingID = Convert.ToInt32(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        drMatchData = dsCIF.Tables["MatchStats"].Rows.Find(matchBookingID);

        drMatchData.BeginEdit();
        drMatchData["PitchID"] = comboBox2.SelectedValue;
        drMatchData["RefereeID"] = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        drMatchData["SessionTime"] = txtTime1.Text + ":" + txtTime2.Text;
        drMatchData["SessionDate"] = DTP.Value.ToShortDateString();
        drMatchData.EndEdit();


        dsCIF.Tables["MatchStats"].Clear();
        daMatchStats.Fill(dsCIF, "MatchStats");
        DGV.Update();
```

when I run the debugger I cant seem to find anything wrong as all of the fields are calculated correctly and the BeginEdit() and EndEdit() are also executing.  The DatagridView appropriately named DGV is not updating and I have checked the Sql-server code and the field also does not update there either.
I have used this method with other tables on other forms and they work fine (I am aware of Injection attacks) is there anything I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are only editing the datarow, not the data in sql server. If you want to update the sql server data you need an update statement. And fix the injection vulnerability. Using parameters is so simple that not doing it when you know it is a problem is just sloppy and lazy.

Comment: Yeah I completely understand its lazy and important but this a draft project to test the relationships between the tables within my database.  Thanks anyway, you helped me realise I was missing something

Comment: Cool glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update the Data Adapter once the edit was finished. I added this line of code in.

```
daMatchStats.Update(dsCIF, "MatchStats");
```

I also removed

```
 dsCIF.Tables["MatchStats"].Clear();
 daMatchStats.Fill(dsCIF, "MatchStats");
```

Now my code looks like this

```
        matchBookingID = Convert.ToInt32(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        drMatchData = dsCIF.Tables["MatchStats"].Rows.Find(matchBookingID);

        drMatchData.BeginEdit();
        drMatchData["PitchID"] = comboBox2.SelectedValue;
        drMatchData["RefereeID"] = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        drMatchData["SessionTime"] = txtTime1.Text + ":" + txtTime2.Text;
        drMatchData["SessionDate"] = DTP.Value.ToShortDateString();
        drMatchData.EndEdit();


      daMatchStats.Update(dsCIF, "MatchStats");
      DGV.Update();
```